# how to store data in multiple tables from single form in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8

hi i wants to store data from one form into 2 db tables but unable to do it:    in my code i wants that teacher can add multiple students,,, that teacher data save into teachers tables and students data saves into students table with that teacher id screen shot of my db table: https://ibb.co/ctr7FDP   https://ibb.co/nwmcnPX   and this is view   https://ibb.co/CBytRCR according to this view i wants to insert multiple students names with their teacher id in student table,,, any guidline  and Note ,,, m using resource route for it

code of teacher controller:

```
  public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'teacher_name'    =>  'required',
    ]);

     $teacher = new Teacher;
     $teacher->teacher_name = $request->teacher_name;
     $teacher->save();

     return redirect('teacher');
}
```

blade file:

```
    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('teacher.store') }}">
  @csrf
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="">Teacher Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="teacher_name" class="form-control input {{ $errors->has('teacher_name') ? 'is-danger' : ''}}" id="" placeholder="Teacher Name">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="text-right">Enter Student Name</label>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div><input type="text" name="student_name[]" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Enter Student Name" /></div>
        </div>
        <p><button class="add_fields">Add More Students</button></p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="submit">

  @include('errors')

</form>
```

teacher model:

```
  public function student()
{
    $this->hasMany('App\Student');
}
```

student model:

```
public function teacher()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Teacher');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public function students()   //student to students
{
    $this->hasMany('App\Student');
}
```

the insertion code should be

```
$teacher->students()->createMany([[$student1],[$student2]]);
```

Comment: now it says Call to a member function createMany() on null   i wrote this code in controller store function of teacher

Comment: have you changed student to students ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are bringing in multiple students in an array from the form in a variable called `student_id`, you can just attach them using Laravel's `attach()` method after you've saved the `teacher`.

```
$teacher->student()->attach($request->get('student_id'));
```

As you have many students to a teacher, I would suggest that you rename the method on the **Teacher** modal to plural (`students`).

Looking over your form, though, I would recommend you capture the `student_id[]` instead of name if this is what your FK is - let the `name` come from the field of students, but in order for this to connect, you need the `ids` in the array, not the `name`.

Comment: Your form looks like it needs some work though - I don't see where you are storing the values of ids/names.  The above will work for you, but I think you need to give some attention to the form and the data sent to it.

Comment: by this public function students()   it says   Call to undefined method App\Teacher::student()   and after it it says Call to a member function attach() on null

Comment: Yes, if you change the name of the relationship, change the name of the relationship method on the code above.  So, if your **Teacher** model's relationship is called `students()`, the code above will now read: `$teacher->students()->attach($request->get('student_id'));`.  None of this will work if you don't add a few things and make some changes as I suggest in the answer.  If you return an array of ids for students from the form in an array called `student_ids`, and you send those ids correctly from your controller to the form, this will do what you want.  Going to take some work though.

Comment: i edit it to this foreach ($request->student_name as $name) {
           $student->student_name = $request->student_name;
           $student->save();
         }   but now it says Creating default object from empty value